# Xades signature validation error

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xades4j

I'm implementing a digital signature on a xml file with Xades-EPES format based on the xades4j library but the other part receiving the signed file return me this error message:

> com.indra.mmdd.signature.exceptions.ValidateException:
>   xades4j.providers.CannotBuildCertificationPathException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>
> digitalsign.verification.status: validate.invalid.signature

Maybe you can tell me if there is something wrong with my code for signing the xml file, so here it is:

```
SignaturePolicyInfoProvider policyInfoProvider = new SignaturePolicyInfoProvider()
        {

            public SignaturePolicyBase getSignaturePolicy()
            {
                return new SignaturePolicyIdentifierProperty(
                        new ObjectIdentifier("oid:/1.2.4.0.9.4.5", IdentifierType.OIDAsURI, "Policy description"),
                        new ByteArrayInputStream("Test policy input stream".getBytes()))
                    .withLocationUrl("http://www.example.com/policy");
            }
        };

        //ingreso la informaciÃ³n de los certificados

        KeyingDataProvider kp = new FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(
                "pkcs12",//tipo de certificado
                rutas.getProperty("rutaCertificado"),//ruta del certificado
                new FirstCertificateSelector(),
                new DirectPasswordProvider("password"),//contraseÃ±a del certificado
                new DirectPasswordProvider("password"),
                true);

        //crea el perfil de firma xades

        XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesEpesSigningProfile(kp, policyInfoProvider);


        Document doc = getDocument(rutas.getProperty("rutaXMLnoFirmados")+nombre+".xml");
        NodeList tag= doc.getElementsByTagName("ext:ExtensionContent");//busca los elementos que concuerden con el string indicado
        Node elemToSign= tag.item(1);//encuentra el nodo en la lista anterior

        System.out.println("inicia el firmador");

        DataObjectDesc dataObjRef = new DataObjectReference("").withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform());//crea un dataobject del xml para firmar


        try {
            XadesSigner signer = new XadesEpesSigningProfile(kp, policyInfoProvider).newSigner();
            System.out.println("Enveloped");
            //new Enveloped(signer).sign(elemToSign);
            signer.sign(new SignedDataObjects(new DataObjectDesc[] { dataObjRef }), elemToSign,SignatureAppendingStrategies.AsFirstChild);//firma el dataobject en el nodo indicado ubicando la firma como primer elemento de dicho nodo
            outputDocument(doc, nombre+".xml");
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><fe:Invoice xmlns:fe="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:clm54217="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:54217:2001" xmlns:clm66411="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:66411:2001" xmlns:clmIANAMIMEMediaType="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:IANAMIMEMediaType:2003" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:sts="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/Structures" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1 ../xsd/DIAN_UBL.xsd urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2 ../../ubl2/common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2 ../../ubl2/common/UBL-QualifiedDatatypes-2.0.xsd">
<ext:UBLExtensions>
<ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:ExtensionContent>
<sts:DianExtensions>
<sts:InvoiceControl>
<sts:InvoiceAuthorization>9000000033328681</sts:InvoiceAuthorization>
<sts:AuthorizationPeriod>
    <cbc:StartDate>2016-07-11</cbc:StartDate>
    <cbc:EndDate>2018-07-11</cbc:EndDate>
</sts:AuthorizationPeriod>
<sts:AuthorizedInvoices>
<sts:Prefix/>
<sts:From>990000000</sts:From>
<sts:To>995000000</sts:To>
</sts:AuthorizedInvoices></sts:InvoiceControl><sts:InvoiceSource><cbc:IdentificationCode listAgencyID="6" listAgencyName="United Nations Economic Commission for Europe" listSchemeURI="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:codelist:gc:CountryIdentificationCode-2.0">CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
</sts:InvoiceSource>
<sts:SoftwareProvider>
    <sts:ProviderID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">800093532</sts:ProviderID>
    <sts:SoftwareID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">ebd0378d705944038be898fd4bd199b5</sts:SoftwareID>
</sts:SoftwareProvider>
<sts:SoftwareSecurityCode schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">0bb9707d114fb83f353e558a3ba167ab0ef0a473bca31aa578b8b46dd613ef99834652a21d2990d94824c1ddda52d504</sts:SoftwareSecurityCode>
</sts:DianExtensions>
</ext:ExtensionContent>
</ext:UBLExtension>

<ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:ExtensionContent><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-3bef2126-2087-4fea-9a0c-dc325030776a">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-3bef2126-2087-4fea-9a0c-dc325030776a-ref0" URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>sCkfhHJx7gT0jP3XnU4RUwWI3Y5CIgapQ/rnjVg40F0=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-3bef2126-2087-4fea-9a0c-dc325030776a-signedprops">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>61hD2h2fyIWmH1pi+yKx1022AtAxOnemt+XNrX+NYnc=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-3bef2126-2087-4fea-9a0c-dc325030776a-sigvalue">
ZrYCc5jl9RSPjyayuJMKn9NjcqrZTlk/So3RwLIu7ctkVu1wruc/ejlcqv8eVN+YrKMu8yfCN8jj;
i6Ji/tkGfCqNWFh4CEeQSsAHsdNzhu7oDtUB5BnWZLSb6NYnIeGhY1jglk+DRO61TfrcbTd9GGYI;
hyF3E4cU0qTLMDh5SHGgMDFO2cDQT0RQa/AXVGxaP4PrjaZzYAFJhILslMn4oQYwX6u1D5aIwJfK;
WgYQ1j8e2g5WujcJAGYjm2kOaYIzhpu2QqHpDVy58uFL2qY9M3/Uhq+pI4O+lpFYcXiu33v6AXlu;
1ImswgddSXlYG3nv8ianI5TX1hm6wAs7Ar2/utpAYQlX5WbrbRQsW9HIfAISCdNK1K+WbYpFsLMP;
QwvU95EKZtIJ7a5jnoI5NzRFZCLTE7BOYcrK33iBEjYPfp5WHwBsOr/AsvhI7GkbngGANfkXP5Rn;
tNMN3nJ85EQsOrwtTdnDNakgkBA/62moo/O/WPSvPVtpJHsL5iHuT6Wlhcg92cHm6myGXtbdBGBU;
Q+PUxbzIZedV4JtzP7v/aw7FvZyhfp+TANHTbyDqQI5TbtbqRTUt5GQQhQsfICInbqL1JlGVYzvf;
13HlogUuTKvuaBQ/DM2DRCaqca1hZv6dnrv9aW8kVxkABY4RsUNgnEJKyMQP/JU8eOeGsgIV08w=
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
MIIFzjCCA7agAwIBAgIJAJSmuDm7MWBVMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMHwxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkNPMRIw;
EAYDVQQIDAlBbnRpb3F1aWExETAPBgNVBAcMCE1lZGVsbGluMQ8wDQYDVQQKDAZTdW1tYW4xEzAR;
BgNVBAsMCkRlc2Fycm9sbG8xIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEWpwZXJlekBzdW1tYW4uY29tMB4XDTE3;
MTAxNzE1MzQ0M1oXDTE4MTAxNzE1MzQ0M1owfDELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ08xEjAQBgNVBAgMCUFudGlv;
cXVpYTERMA8GA1UEBwwITWVkZWxsaW4xDzANBgNVBAoMBlN1bW1hbjETMBEGA1UECwwKRGVzYXJy;
b2xsbzEgMB4GCSqGSIb3DQEJARYRanBlcmV6QHN1bW1hbi5jb20wggIiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUA;
A4ICDwAwggIKAoICAQCzXTpR0xLxY52dJa5nYBor/5KyBBqmE82Mhvi0Fi5ai3tnT8Ywbt4m8eZz;
u+LoXod/u3eNWsr96dvFolQyEe25ctRPooREEsZ12yM1m718+dFkuba0imhUXH3GPDnsEtzGWYGh;
2aFQFSuPlWhPEVuUz3Op4vMRkQofxW1jqAh8thPYsnTkHcmfE/7L89JksJUzyctVfl0P2rj5Pf0v;
vYHG746yBrN7hBZ7Git083h0vkU+6OHfri9V/qjxq4nNpDq5lWQwDsfFLRwqUcj6fvNx5/8sL5gB;
N8YH9v7q/lJJefCt7LEPktGbltVQFkd+vyhWYpI0vuDJDG1JI/AArU5mPCPXyjrFaE+2c99bIYXQ;
sptDVQmDmjgg8rNg/c5bTNkBQg3QCgPZpHZnx9UxhP6Eu1fInt5SUU8/qfcTCjDffNvL+rH193UR;
o6fEEc37l9rzGhuNE1dycJsUeu59SEWNb9SeOjYGth2h0XBhSIg92SxpeaQ04ik8ciY/1MY4COpP;
D4FUCta3WdZqjK19SEO7TKYoK7jUsFM0aNJ3gAUC4J8wjbNb8asqTpz7cFMIsbZeQwegrwimQCwT;
TY58QYfmyxL4S12dwnPgWcaWQGDUv4a2aiajHVGMQcYpYb9xBBcuew1gHHl3spjO1oLfsCYXBzXI;
kcxuTJY/Xy10N/w3UwIDAQABo1MwUTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUNb7AgKv/cGd6eCPkI2WyozBPoYQwHwYD;
VR0jBBgwFoAUNb7AgKv/cGd6eCPkI2WyozBPoYQwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zANBgkqhkiG9w0B;
AQsFAAOCAgEAJwqi/VbbyAeplkbMUurrIPJkk6c2oXpVPNmBc62FpNNtJ1yzL8fOdpzWFs4F5t6G;
jOlhK1rlnfH0po3UvcG4bVPf1cXj8pCo0ywy8qI2DVGFJCQjh9u75Rr+7vuGmJ8SsynI1tzvTB/s;
xRz7yNoRuiYwBJW7p7WkO60F0w8pUfXiFqSulqHhK6gfabyBl3t9mO6bpPx8VRVhATp5CnyKYWH0;
0qbwiqqh9PEdzY6079MIECCvscqRltTBfJZZMkmVoxDfXCEDfDcfaZd4cWwOLYVXv9YDQ9snR6cw;
JIrhN9mAQv62oimuNm6cE8gyhPTbDUAZOZy05kT8Vdh1sAGyHR/XnOygEZD1ivTee6vOWGNEZf97;
OBFuRUQMuP3E/84pIAs0PehO1+IIO2w1IiV9Je00PY3PazfVrKRIV1glYo+e9ip45xXXgemB+ojR;
Ypkr4WwmZnB+FV5vyYsRANvU8UHlr0SZhXkdfAnaz5hbiplzJwHwPU/uQxs8rgvwUsQdzTB1XZJK;
f1Sci7UyKAMt5iWul//g3BKQcKALhIyu71KoQLoV1GnUPcQqXa/GOoh3gGIqnJIaMd5rKgHAtyiE;
qlw+WIXbo6YfWDLW7EvGQIFlum7qBQzaaH+F5fFTT0wnpdzkP/krkb2XmrRcgNlDOQ8aOrSZGIDq;
H65stf+TTWY=
</ds:X509Certificate>
<ds:X509SubjectName>1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16116a706572657a4073756d6d616e2e636f6d,OU=Desarrollo,O=Summan,L=Medellin,ST=Antioquia,C=CO</ds:X509SubjectName>
<ds:X509IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16116a706572657a4073756d6d616e2e636f6d,OU=Desarrollo,O=Summan,L=Medellin,ST=Antioquia,C=CO</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>10711451321840525397</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</ds:X509IssuerSerial>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Target="#xmldsig-3bef2126-2087-4fea-9a0c-dc325030776a"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-3bef2126-2087-4fea-9a0c-dc325030776a-signedprops"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2017-11-22T11:49:17.637-05:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>DK+4edv28PboiT2oQVklof4FGmee3eCZCvIzL3ZQSOw=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16116a706572657a4073756d6d616e2e636f6d,OU=Desarrollo,O=Summan,L=Medellin,ST=Antioquia,C=CO</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>10711451321840525397</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier><xades:SignaturePolicyId><xades:SigPolicyId><xades:Identifier Qualifier="OIDAsURI">oid:/1.2.4.0.9.4.5</xades:Identifier><xades:Description>Policy description</xades:Description></xades:SigPolicyId><xades:SigPolicyHash><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>MaW9PDxJruPHhjBVAMWyrF9zP+kMnNqkoQOUXxDDGAk=</ds:DigestValue></xades:SigPolicyHash><xades:SigPolicyQualifiers><xades:SigPolicyQualifier><xades:SPURI>http://www.example.com/policy</xades:SPURI></xades:SigPolicyQualifier></xades:SigPolicyQualifiers></xades:SignaturePolicyId></xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
</ext:ExtensionContent>
</ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>

<cbc:UBLVersionID>UBL 2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:ProfileID>DIAN 1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
<cbc:ID>990000001</cbc:ID>
<cbc:UUID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y AduanasNacionales)">48a1d7560167b453bffa13898de8cec6faeaf11e</cbc:UUID>
<cbc:IssueDate>2017-11-22</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:IssueTime>11:49:14</cbc:IssueTime>
<cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listAgencyID="195" listAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" listSchemeURI="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/InvoiceType">1</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
<cbc:Note>Informacion libre sobre el documento</cbc:Note>
<cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>COP</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>

<fe:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
    <fe:Party>
        <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="31">800093532</cbc:ID>
        </cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>Summan S.A.S</cbc:Name>
        </cac:PartyName>
        <fe:PhysicalLocation>
            <fe:Address>
                <cbc:Department>Antioquia</cbc:Department>
                <cbc:CityName>Medellin</cbc:CityName>
                <cac:AddressLine>
                    <cbc:Line>Calle 13 # 43D 19 Oficina 201</cbc:Line>
                </cac:AddressLine>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </fe:Address>
        </fe:PhysicalLocation>
        <fe:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:TaxLevelCode>2</cbc:TaxLevelCode>
            <cac:TaxScheme/>
        </fe:PartyTaxScheme>
        <fe:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>Summan S.A.S</cbc:RegistrationName>
        </fe:PartyLegalEntity></fe:Party>
</fe:AccountingSupplierParty>

<fe:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>2</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
    <fe:Party>
        <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="31">43466338</cbc:ID>
        </cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>NOTARIA ONCE DE MEDELLIN</cbc:Name>
        </cac:PartyName>
        <fe:PhysicalLocation>
            <fe:Address>
                <cbc:Department>ANTIOQUIA</cbc:Department>
                <cbc:CityName>MEDELLIN</cbc:CityName>
                <cac:AddressLine>
                    <cbc:Line>CARRERA 43A # 1 - 77, LOCAL 2, EDIFICIO BANCO CAJA SOCIAL</cbc:Line>
                </cac:AddressLine>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </fe:Address>
        </fe:PhysicalLocation>
        <fe:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:TaxLevelCode>0</cbc:TaxLevelCode>
            <cac:TaxScheme/>
        </fe:PartyTaxScheme>
        <fe:Person>
            <cbc:FirstName/>
            <cbc:FamilyName/>
            <cbc:MiddleName/>
        </fe:Person>
    </fe:Party>
    </fe:AccountingCustomerParty>
            <fe:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">256569.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>
            <fe:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">1350366.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
                <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">256569.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
                <cbc:Percent>19</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxCategory>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:TaxCategory>
            </fe:TaxSubtotal>
        </fe:TaxTotal>
            <fe:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>
            <fe:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">1350366.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
                <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
                <cbc:Percent>0</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxCategory>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>06</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:TaxCategory>
            </fe:TaxSubtotal>
        </fe:TaxTotal>
            <fe:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>
            <fe:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">1350366.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
                <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
                <cbc:Percent>0</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxCategory>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>07</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:TaxCategory>
            </fe:TaxSubtotal>
        </fe:TaxTotal>
            <fe:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">6015.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>
            <fe:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">1350366.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
                <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">6015.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
                <cbc:Percent>0</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxCategory>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>05</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:TaxCategory>
            </fe:TaxSubtotal>
        </fe:TaxTotal>

        <fe:LegalMonetaryTotal>
            <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">1350366.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
            <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="COP">1350366.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
            <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="COP">1600920.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
        </fe:LegalMonetaryTotal>

                <fe:InvoiceLine>
            <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">1200000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
            <fe:Item>
                <cbc:Description>RENTA EQUIPO IMPRESION Y MULTIFUNCION (4)</cbc:Description>
            </fe:Item>
            <fe:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">1200000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            </fe:Price>
        </fe:InvoiceLine>
            <fe:InvoiceLine>
            <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>3944</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">134096.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
            <fe:Item>
                <cbc:Description>EXCEDENTE IMPRESION</cbc:Description>
            </fe:Item>
            <fe:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">34.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            </fe:Price>
        </fe:InvoiceLine>
            <fe:InvoiceLine>
            <cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>1627</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">16270.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
            <fe:Item>
                <cbc:Description>PAGINAS ESCANEADAS</cbc:Description>
            </fe:Item>
            <fe:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">10.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            </fe:Price>
        </fe:InvoiceLine>
    </fe:Invoice>
```

----UPDATE----

I've got a new certificate that should work because is an official one but I have the same problem. (I put a link because the new xml would reach the character limit of the post)

[signed Xml](http://www.mediafire.com/file/thm611dmedd292b/face_f0800093532003b023382.xml)

Comment: To analyze your issue we will need the verification code, or at least a sample signature, not the signing code. Generally it is not possible to confirm if a code works without having tested it. But in this case the exception it is clear: The verification part is not  trusting the signing certificate. Causes 1) The root CA is not present in the server truststore 2) You didn't include the full certification chain in the XMLDsig signature

Comment: My first guess would be option 2). The keystore probably doesn't have the full certification path, and as such it won't be included in the signature

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have edited the post with my signed xml below. I think you're right with the certification path guess but I don't have much knowledge about how to address that issue, I'm kind of a newbie with all this digital signature stuff, so I'll greatly appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: The certificate and the signature are invalid. They include the `&#13;` character. May be is a typo copying the signature into SO. Removing that character set, I can see that your certificate is self-signed, so ensure that the server part has imported the certificate into its truststore

Comment: Hi @pedrofb indeed that was a typo, I don't know how it got there but it appears when I open the xml file in an editor, when opened on a browser it looks fine. So if the certificate was imported in the server side it should work fine?  The certificate is self signed just for test sake, it would be replaced when the file is verified successfully. What was that about keystore not having the full certification path preventing it from being in the signature?

Comment: The certificate must be imported in the truststore used by server to verify the signature. When you use a certificate issued by a CA with intermmediate certificates, you need to addto the signature the entire certification chain, so your keystore have to contain all required certificates

Comment: I'm going to contact the server side to make sure they have my certificate, on the other hand, how do I Know if my signature has the entire certifiaction chain? I'm using the xades4j library and following the instruccions on the wiki to make my signer (https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/DefiningKeyingData).

Comment: @juanjoseperezhernandez Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: Hi, there was indeed a problem with my certificate. I will update when I get the new one. 

@FuriosoJack Me comuniqué con la entidad que me exige el certificado (Dian) y me dicen que el certificado que estaba utilizando no es valido para ellos, que debo comprar uno a una entidad avalada por la Dian. Estoy esperando que aprueben la compra en mi empresa.

Comment: Excelente y sabes cuales son las entidades certificadoras aprobadas por la dian, ando varado por el mismo problema

Comment: @FuriosoJack las puedes encontrar aquí:
http://www.onac.org.co/modulos/contenido/default.asp?idmodulo=599

Comment: I've got the official certificated and when I replaced the old one I got ne the next error:

**xades4j.verification.UnexpectedJCAException: The keystore couldn't be initialized...**

All I did was change one .p12 file for the other and now it's not working anymore.

I have edited the post to include the full traceback error.

Comment: See where the new exception says 'Caused by ... keystore password was incorrect'? You need to use the password that was used to create (encrypt) the new p12.

Comment: @dave_thompson085 I did, I replaced the old password aswell, That's why I don't understand the error.

Comment: Found the problem respect of "keystore password was incorrect", it was some bug that insisted on looking for the old p12 file even though I change the properties file. Please ignore the comments about that issue. Still having issue with the validation of the signature though. I will erase that part because it has nothing to do with the original reason of the post.